# Keras save models and load models using image

Tags: python, pandas, keras

How can I save these as an image of a network and then load them as a image.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_dim=3250))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(613, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
model.save_weights('.hdf5')
model.load_weights('.hdf5')
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'saving the models as a image'?

Comment: So once I load the weights, I want to be able to save it as an image of the network.@Prophecies then just load that image then having to rerun through the process.

Comment: You still have not clarified what you mean by an "image" in this context.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to store the architecture of your network in addition to weights? 
You can use the methods `model.to_json()` or `model.to_yaml()` to generate the description of the architecture in the appropriate format and write it to a file.